# Is it possible to pipe output of 'hg log' command to secondary command?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to write a small script for my team that automatically updates the feature branche to a case and then creates a branch for review. I've got the commands down manually but I'm having trouble making it a bit more hands off.

For now, I want to use this templated command:

```
 hg log --rev <changeset> --template "{branch}\n"
```

Which returns the branch name of a changset. Then I would like to remove a portion of the name and prepend a string. For example, a branch would be named `case-1234-FeatureDescription` and I would want to be creating a branch named `review-1234-FeatureDescription`

Ideally, I would like to pipe the output of this command to the branch command

```
hg branch <result-of-previous-command>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You suggest to create a branch by a name which you just extraced from the logs of the very same repo. That doesn't exactly look like it can succeed as it already exists.

Additionally, it likely is probably not a good idea to create a named branch for each review process as branch names are persistent. You might consider to use bookmarks for that purpose as they can be deleted without trace from the repo after review is completed.

I'd suggest to use - without piping - something like

```
hg bookmark -r CHANGESET $(hg log --rev CHANGESET -T"{branch}")-review
```

Comment: I apologize -- there would be another command or some sort of regex between them to change the name of the branch from 'feature' to 'review'.

Comment: SO won't let me edit my previous comment, I apologize -- As is, we create review branches to see the latest version of the code changes. Our review tool (fogbugz/kiln) doesn't recognize bookmarks as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Well, sure, you can create a new branch in a similar way as you create a bookmark. But honestly, creating a named branch for each review process sounds pretty non-standard and like something you'll regret after you have several dozens of such branches you never will be able to get rid off. You should complain to fogbugz, they actually should know mercurial better than to do this.

Comment: Additionally: are you sure that kiln uses mercurial branches instead of clones of the repo? http://help.fogcreek.com/7984/mercurial-branches-versus-kiln-branches